# Push selection to another array for storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

Hi wrote probably my first JavaScript code, I have a slight problem with it.

I want to randomly select a country and then the random selection should be added to the array called `sel_count_arr`

so if you push the button 5 times then five random countries should be pushed to the `sel_count_arr`

the selecting random countries part is working, but pushing the selection to the empty arrey is not.

can someone help me to figure this out?

```html
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('countries').innerHTML = random_countries(country_list)">Click for random country</button>
<p id="countries"> </p>

<h3>Selected countries:</h3>
<p id="selected_countries"></p>

<script>
function random_countries(country_list)
{
 return country_list[Math.floor(Math.random()*country_list.length)];
}
var country_list = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua &amp; Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas"
 ,"Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","British Virgin Islands"
 ,"Brunei","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Burundi","Cambodia","Cameroon","Canada","Cape Verde","Cayman Islands","Chad","Chile","China","Colombia","Congo","Cook Islands","Costa Rica"
 ,"Cote D Ivoire","Croatia","Cruise Ship","Cuba","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea"
 ,"Estonia","Ethiopia","Falkland Islands","Faroe Islands","Fiji","Finland","France","French Polynesia","French West Indies","Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana"
 ,"Gibraltar","Greece","Greenland","Grenada","Guam","Guatemala","Guernsey","Guinea","Guinea Bissau","Guyana","Haiti","Honduras","Hong Kong","Hungary","Iceland","India"
 ,"Indonesia","Iran","Iraq","Ireland","Isle of Man","Israel","Italy","Jamaica","Japan","Jersey","Jordan","Kazakhstan","Kenya","Kuwait","Kyrgyz Republic","Laos","Latvia"
 ,"Lebanon","Lesotho","Liberia","Libya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Macau","Macedonia","Madagascar","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Mali","Malta","Mauritania"
 ,"Mauritius","Mexico","Moldova","Monaco","Mongolia","Montenegro","Montserrat","Morocco","Mozambique","Namibia","Nepal","Netherlands","Netherlands Antilles","New Caledonia"
 ,"New Zealand","Nicaragua","Niger","Nigeria","Norway","Oman","Pakistan","Palestine","Panama","Papua New Guinea","Paraguay","Peru","Philippines","Poland","Portugal"
 ,"Puerto Rico","Qatar","Reunion","Romania","Russia","Rwanda","Saint Pierre &amp; Miquelon","Samoa","San Marino","Satellite","Saudi Arabia","Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles"
 ,"Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia","Slovenia","South Africa","South Korea","Spain","Sri Lanka","St Kitts &amp; Nevis","St Lucia","St Vincent","St. Lucia","Sudan"
 ,"Suriname","Swaziland","Sweden","Switzerland","Syria","Taiwan","Tajikistan","Tanzania","Thailand","Timor L'Este","Togo","Tonga","Trinidad &amp; Tobago","Tunisia"
 ,"Turkey","Turkmenistan","Turks &amp; Caicos","Uganda","Ukraine","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","United States","United States Minor Outlying Islands","Uruguay"
 ,"Uzbekistan","Venezuela","Vietnam","Virgin Islands (US)","Yemen","Zambia","Zimbabwe"];

var sel_count_arr = [];

document.getElementById("selected_countries").innerHTML = sel_count_arr.push(random_countries(country_list));

</script>
```

Comment: That question was like asking "I am doing 1 * 1 why am I not getting 1 + 1". You are not updating sel_count_arr in onclick, so it is not getting updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You better use a function for the event and push the random value to the array and show the array by using `innerHTML` for it.

```js
function fn() {
    var random = random_countries(country_list);
    sel_count_arr.push(random);
    document.getElementById('countries').innerHTML = random;
    document.getElementById('selected_countries').innerHTML = sel_count_arr.join(', ');
}

function random_countries(country_list) {
    return country_list[Math.floor(Math.random() * country_list.length)];
}

var country_list = ["Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antigua &amp; Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "British Virgin Islands", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Congo", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Cote D Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cruise Ship", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Falkland Islands", "Faroe Islands", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "French Polynesia", "French West Indies", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guernsey", "Guinea", "Guinea Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Isle of Man", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jersey", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyz Republic", "Laos", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macau", "Macedonia", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mexico", "Moldova", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Namibia", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palestine", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Reunion", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Saint Pierre &amp; Miquelon", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Satellite", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "South Africa", "South Korea", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "St Kitts &amp; Nevis", "St Lucia", "St Vincent", "St. Lucia", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Timor L'Este", "Togo", "Tonga", "Trinidad &amp; Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Turks &amp; Caicos", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States", "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Virgin Islands (US)", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"],
    sel_count_arr = [];
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="fn()">Click for random country</button>
<p id="countries"> </p>
<h3>Selected countries:</h3>
<p id="selected_countries"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('countries').innerHTML = random_countries(country_list)">Click for random country</button>
<p id="countries"> </p>

<h3>Selected countries:</h3>
<p id="selected_countries"></p>

<script>
function random_countries(country_list)
{
 const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*country_list.length);
 document.getElementById("selected_countries").innerHTML = sel_count_arr.push(country_list[randomNumber]); // push the country on button click
 return country_list[randomNumber];
}
var country_list = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua &amp; Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas"
 ,"Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","British Virgin Islands"
 ,"Brunei","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Burundi","Cambodia","Cameroon","Canada","Cape Verde","Cayman Islands","Chad","Chile","China","Colombia","Congo","Cook Islands","Costa Rica"
 ,"Cote D Ivoire","Croatia","Cruise Ship","Cuba","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea"
 ,"Estonia","Ethiopia","Falkland Islands","Faroe Islands","Fiji","Finland","France","French Polynesia","French West Indies","Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana"
 ,"Gibraltar","Greece","Greenland","Grenada","Guam","Guatemala","Guernsey","Guinea","Guinea Bissau","Guyana","Haiti","Honduras","Hong Kong","Hungary","Iceland","India"
 ,"Indonesia","Iran","Iraq","Ireland","Isle of Man","Israel","Italy","Jamaica","Japan","Jersey","Jordan","Kazakhstan","Kenya","Kuwait","Kyrgyz Republic","Laos","Latvia"
 ,"Lebanon","Lesotho","Liberia","Libya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Macau","Macedonia","Madagascar","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Mali","Malta","Mauritania"
 ,"Mauritius","Mexico","Moldova","Monaco","Mongolia","Montenegro","Montserrat","Morocco","Mozambique","Namibia","Nepal","Netherlands","Netherlands Antilles","New Caledonia"
 ,"New Zealand","Nicaragua","Niger","Nigeria","Norway","Oman","Pakistan","Palestine","Panama","Papua New Guinea","Paraguay","Peru","Philippines","Poland","Portugal"
 ,"Puerto Rico","Qatar","Reunion","Romania","Russia","Rwanda","Saint Pierre &amp; Miquelon","Samoa","San Marino","Satellite","Saudi Arabia","Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles"
 ,"Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia","Slovenia","South Africa","South Korea","Spain","Sri Lanka","St Kitts &amp; Nevis","St Lucia","St Vincent","St. Lucia","Sudan"
 ,"Suriname","Swaziland","Sweden","Switzerland","Syria","Taiwan","Tajikistan","Tanzania","Thailand","Timor L'Este","Togo","Tonga","Trinidad &amp; Tobago","Tunisia"
 ,"Turkey","Turkmenistan","Turks &amp; Caicos","Uganda","Ukraine","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","United States","United States Minor Outlying Islands","Uruguay"
 ,"Uzbekistan","Venezuela","Vietnam","Virgin Islands (US)","Yemen","Zambia","Zimbabwe"];

var sel_count_arr = [];



</script>
```